# Rails - adding attributes on a user before it's created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

When a user registers with twitter I'm trying to add his name, location, etc. to his user record. I think I want to do something like `user.build`

Here is the controller. This is what happens:

```
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omni)
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Logged In!"
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
    else
      session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
```

When a user doesn't exist with twitter, the user is redirected to the registration path where they finish registering. I want to add the extra stuff from twitter to their yet to be saved user account. I can't do it in the `user.apply_omniauth(omni)` method because that saves to the authentications table.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZaMEw4B4

Comment: That wasn't the most detailed answer I've ever gotten, but after a few minutes I figured out what was going on! Thanks! If you want credit for the answer, put something a little more explicit down as an answer and I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a flag in `apply_omniauth` method to make a decision to save or not.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
# def apply_omniauth(omniauth) => def apply_omniauth(omniauth, save_it)
# apply_omniauth with save it flag
def apply_omniauth(omniauth, save_it = false)
  case omniauth['provider']
  when 'facebook'
    self.apply_facebook(omniauth)
  end
  self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email']
  if email.blank ? build_authentications(omniauth, save_it)
end

#build authentications
def build_authentications(omniauth, save_it = false)
  auth_params = {: provider = > omniauth['provider'],
      : uid = > omniauth['uid'],
      : token = > (omniauth['credentials']['token'] rescue nil)
  }
  if save_it authentications.create!(auth_params)
  else authentications.build(auth_params)
  end
end

#force to save
def apply_omniauth!(omniauth)
  apply_omniauth(omniauth, true)
end
```